# Metro app, parsing JSON data in C# error

Tags: c#, json, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to parse json data for reddit comments in a Windows 8 Metro app. I have been able to successfully parse the homepage json data using JSONObject.Parse(), but when trying to parse data for a comments page, the parse failed. The data in question is here:

Homepage: Can Parse

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.reddit.com/.json

Comments: Cannot Parse

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/vt3wk/proving_grounds_playable_on_live_on_all_3_regions/.json

The problem appears to be that the root object of the comments json is an array, while the root object of the homepage is a normal object. However, jsonlint.com tells me that the json is valid in both cases.

Can anyone tell me why this occurs?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. Instead of JSONObject.Parse, JsonArray.Parse had to be called.